# Obtener el nombre de un data.frame

Tags: r

Me gustaría obtener el nombre de un data.frame en R.

Por ejemplo:

si tengo el data.frame Usuarios y lo paso como parámetro en una función, me gustaría obtener "Usuarios" y no los datos.

> name(Usuarios) #Función inventada pero que simboliza lo que quiero que haga.
>
> "Usuarios"

Por más que busco no encuentro, si es que existe, la función en R que lo realice. Con rownames() obtengo los de la fila, con colnames() o names() los de las columnas pero no el nombre del data.frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podés usar [`substitute`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substitute.html)

```
prueba <-0
substitute(prueba) ## Retorna "prueba"
```

Comment: Funciona, gracias :D